# WCF and jQuery autocomplete plugin

Tags: asp.net, jquery, wcf, autocomplete

Good afternoon

I'm facing a trouble, trying to figure out how to use this [autocomplete plugin](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/) and make it consume my WCF service method. The WCF is correctly published and working.

What can be done to autocomplete plugin work or is there another clever way to make autocomplete work with WCF and get chosen Person.Id and Person.Name?

Below some things I've been working by now:

*WCF Service*

```
public class Person {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public static List<Person> List(){
      /*long query supressed to no be annoying :) */
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IChatService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
     UriTemplate = "GetPeople", 
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Person> GetPeople();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return Person.List();
    }
}
```

*Now the aspx page:*

```
....
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.bgiframe.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.ajaxQueue.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/thickbox-compressed.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/lib/thickbox.css" />

<script>
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#<%=peopleNames.ClientID%>').autocomplete("http://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc/GetPeople", {
            width: 260,
            selectFirst: false
        });
        $("#<%=peopleNames.ClientID%>").result(function (event, data, formatted) {
            alert('ok');
            if (data) {
                alert($(this).parent().next().find("input").val(data[1]));
            }
        });
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="peopleNames" runat="server" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Just for testing purpose, the idea is to let web user type a name, and jQuery would call WCF service http://localhost/MyService/GetPeople to list all people in SQL Server database (in future GetPeople method will have a string argument).

The jquery **autocomplete** plugin seems to be good, but I'm not sure yet which js files I'll need to make it work on my local computer. And now I can't make it work or debug it, even when it comes to show an alert();

Comment: What about the [DataConctract] [DataMember] attributes in Person Class?

Comment: Done. I see that WCF is working well. I'm taking a look at  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote to see what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just coded this together, using [the autocomplete from jQuery UI v1.8rc3](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) (I think that is an old version; it works with jQuery 1.4.2), and WCF 3.5 (also one rev out of date).  Here's how I did mine.

*WCF Service*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Ionic.Samples.Webservices._2010.Nov
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:Ionic.Samples" )]
    public interface ICompletionService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                   RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   UriTemplate = "getcompletions/{fragment}")]
        List<String> GetCompletions(string fragment);
    }


    [ServiceBehavior(Name="WcfJqueryAutoComplete",  
                     Namespace="urn:Ionic.Samples",
                     InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single,    // one instance for all requests
                     IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]

    public class WcfJqueryAutoComplete : ICompletionService
    {
        private List<String> allCandidates;

        public WcfJqueryAutoComplete()
        {
            allCandidates = new List<String>
                {
          "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
          "December", "Yammer", "Yaw", "Yawn", "Auspiscious",
          "Arbitrage", "Arbiter", "Arbor", "Ardor", "Ardent",
          "Concrete", "Conscious", "Uptight", "Uplevel", "Friend",
          "Depend", "Deepend", "Deepen", "Decommit", "Right", "Now",
          "Knowledge", "Knight", "Know", "Knickers", "Wow", "Holy",
           ...
                };
        }

        public List<String> GetCompletions(String fragment)
        {
            var frag = fragment.ToUpper();
            // use LINQ to select candidates from the in-memory list.
            // You could replace this with a SQL query.
            var selection = from candidate in allCandidates
                where candidate.ToUpper().StartsWith(frag)
                select candidate;

            return new List<String>(selection);
        }
    }
}
```

*The .svc file*

```
<%@ ServiceHost
Language="C#"
Debug="true"
Service="Ionic.Samples.Webservices._2010.Nov.WcfJqueryAutoComplete"
%>
```

*The relevant WCF .config info*

```
<system.serviceModel>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="JsonServiceEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>


  <services>
    <service
        name="Ionic.Samples.Webservices._2010.Nov.WcfJqueryAutoComplete"
        >
      <endpoint
         address               = ""
         binding               = "webHttpBinding"
         contract              = "Ionic.Samples.Webservices._2010.Nov.ICompletionService"
         behaviorConfiguration = "JsonServiceEndpointBehavior"
         bindingNamespace      = "urn:Ionic.Samples"
         />

    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

*The Javascript logic*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--

  var ajaxUrlBase1 = "/services/WcfJqueryAutoComplete.svc/";

  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#input1").autocomplete({
          // The source option can be an array of terms.  In this case, if
          // the typed characters appear in any position in a term, then the
          // term is included in the autocomplete list.
          // The source option can also be a function that performs the search,
          // and calls a response function with the matched entries.
          source: function(req, responseFn) {
              $.ajax({
                  url     : ajaxUrlBase1 + "getcompletions/" + req.term,
                  cache   : false,
                  type    : "GET", // http method
                  dataType: "json",
                  error   : function(XMLHttpRequest,status,error){
                      alert("Error p1 s(" + status + ") e(" + error + ")");
                  },

                  success : function(msg, arg2, xhr){
                      try {
                        if (msg !== null) {
                          responseFn(msg);
                        } else {
                          alert("msg is null");
                        }
                      }
                      catch(e) {
                        alert("exception: " + e);
                      }
                  }
              });
          },

          select: function(value, data){
            // whatever you like here
          }
      });
  });

  -->
</script>
```

This works nicely.

---

ps: for debugging jQuery, I have found that the debugger tools included in FF or IE8+ are invaluable.  In IE8 press F12 to get the debugger console.

Also, when developing I often set up a div, with id=msgs, to collect diagnostic information from javascript logic.  Then I use this kind of function to drop info into it, at different stages of execution.

```
function addMessage(msg, clear){
    if (clear !== null && clear) {
      $('#msgs').html("");
    }
    $('#msgs').append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The wierd thing here is that the piece above `$('#example').autocomplete(source: function (request, response) {$.ajax({...` is never fired. But when I put `$('#example').autocomplete(myDataArray)` it works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.  what piece is never "fired"?

Comment: the source nested function `$.ajax(...` was never getting fired, but your answer helped me somehow with another thing. Now I got autocomplete working after reading autocomplete plugin documentation in Google Code http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/wiki/Documentation. Here is my working sample:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173999/jquery-ajax-call-working-and-autocomplete-not-working-with-wcf/4174878#4174878